# Inverse trignometry

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

The following function models the length $L$ of each day (in minutes) in Manila, $t$ days after the spring equinox, which is March 22.

$$ L(t) = 52 \sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{365}\right)+728$$

What is the first time after March 22 that the day length hits 700 minutes?

***what I have tried***:

[image: Solution]

So I get $t = -28.5$ which is negative and days cannot be in negative

please help me in solving the problem

**Update**:

In the Image above sin-1 is $\sin^{-1}$

**Hint**:

The first 700-minute day is 216 days after March 22

Comment: Whenever you solve a problem involving trigonometric functions, there are usually an infinite number of algebraically valid solutions.  -0.57 is one possible value of $\sin^{-1}(-0.54)$, but there are infinitely many others.  Do you know how to find them?

Comment: yes there are infinite solution. I think you mean $-0.54 + 2\pi n$

Comment: I think you meant $-0.57 + 2\pi n$?  But yes, I think you have the right idea.  So, in this case, you could try seeing if $-0.57 + 2\pi$ gives you something physically reasonable.  But there is also another set of solutions not covered by $-0.57 + 2\pi$.  Remember that $\sin^{-1}$ gives two values between $0$ and $2\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$52\sin \left(\frac{2\pi\cdot t}{365}\right) + 728 = 700 \to \sin \left(\frac{2\pi\cdot t}{365}\right) = \dfrac{700-728}{52} = -0.538 \to \dfrac{2\pi\cdot t}{365} = \sin^{-1} (-.538) + 2\pi = -0.57+2\pi = 5.72 \to t = \dfrac{5.72\cdot 365}{2\pi} = 332$ ( days ).

**Edit**:To get $216$ days, all you need to do is change $-0.57$ to $-(\pi - 0.57)$, and then add $2\pi$ to it and get $-(\pi - 0.57) + 2\pi = \pi + 0.57 = 3.71$. Thus:

$ t= \dfrac{3.71\cdot 365}{2\pi} \approx 216$ (days).

Comment: $-0.57+2\pi n$ gives one set of solutions for $\sin^{-1}(0.54)$, but there's another independent set of solutions for $\sin^{-1}(0.54)$.

Comment: ok @nukeguy i got your point
 $x=2\pi n+sin​^{−1}​​A or x=2\pi n+(π−sin​^{−1}​​A)$ this might be general solution and BRIC-Fan answer also one possible solution

Comment: Not a problem....CJ

Answer (score 1):

Trigonometric aspects have been discussed in comments and answer; so, I shall propose another possible approach.

You need to solve the equation $$L(t) = 52 \sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{365}\right)+728=700$$ and you are looking for the closest solution; so, let us write the equation as $$f(t)=52 \sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{365}\right)+28$$ and use Newton method with $t_0=\frac{365}{2}$ which is the middle point between the maximum and the minimum of the function.

Newton iterates are given by $$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{f(t_n)}{f'(t_n)}$$ which in the case of the problem gives $$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{365 \left(52 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  t_n}{365}\right)+28\right) \sec
   \left(\frac{2 \pi  t_n}{365}\right)}{104 \pi }$$ Then, the following iterates are generated : $213.780$, $215.515$, $215.531$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Comment: Thanks Claude, btw why 216 is first possible solution?

Comment: Because it is between the first maximum and the first minimum which bracket the target value.

Answer (score 0):

$52\sin(\dfrac{2\pi ⋅t}{365})+728=700\implies \sin(\dfrac{2\pi ⋅t}{365})=\dfrac{700−728}{52}=−0.538\implies \dfrac{2\pi ⋅t}{365}=\sin^{−1}(−.538)+2\pi =−0.57+2\pi =5.72\implies t=\dfrac{5.72⋅365}{2\pi } =332$ (days).

**Edit:** To get $216$ days, all you need to do is change $−0.57$ to $−(\pi −0.57)$, and then add $2\pi $ to it and get $−(\pi −0.57)+2\pi =\pi +0.57=3.71$. Thus: $t=3.71⋅3652π≈216$ (days).